# Ошибка "Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект"

Tags: c#

Вот упрощенный код моей программы. Помогите разобраться, новичку. Огромное спасибо!

```
class Program
    {

        public struct dtTable
        {
            float cash;

            int quancar1;

            dtTable calc()
            {
                dtTable myTable = new dtTable();

                int quancar1 = 0

                        quancar1 = quancar1 + 10;

                }
                return (myTable);
            }

            public void SetDataTable(dtTable inData)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Всего: {0}", quancar1);
            }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                SetDataTable(calc()); // ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: вам же русским языком написали, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к нестатическому методу из статического

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте метод SetDataTable статическим (напишите в начале модификатор static) - и будет вам счастье.

Судя по вопросу, вы не понимаете, что такое объект, ссылочный тип и статический член класса.
Прочитайте основы.
Можете посмотреть небольшой [урок](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W731ZUPME0k&list=PL517665BA72656E8B&index=20) или какой-нибудь другой, но обязательно разберитесь, что такое объект.